# Code coverage test in Visual Studio 2010? How?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

I have a simple project on C#.NET and have written it in Visual Studio 2010. I am a newbie in C# and Visual Studio.

I have written some unit tests, and they pass ok, but how can I test code coverage?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: Well, I created unit test using the "Create unit test" menu in VS2010.
Should I use NUnit?

Comment: I use NUnit personally, but that's just my choice. I find the MSTest user experience a bit confusing. I'll give you an answer that works with both NUnit and MSTest. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use NUnit as my testing framework and use TestDriven.Net to run VS2010's code coverage. This also works with MSTest i.e. Visual Studio tests. First you need to get hold of TestDriven.Net:

http://www.testdriven.net/download.aspx

Once TestDriven.Net is installed, you will get some extra items added to your Solution Explorer context menu e.g. right-click a project and you'll have some TestDriven options under "Test With". One of those options is "Coverage" which will run your unit tests with code coverage and then display the code coverage results window. Works very well.

**Update**

Of course you can only get code coverage in Visual Studio 2010 if you have a version that actually supports it i.e. Premium or Ultimate.

Comment: Note that the VS/MSTest *coverage* tools are not included with all VS SKUs (or at least, it didn't used to be). TestDriven,NET can't use them if they aren't in the installed edition.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. I hadn't thought about that. I am using Ultimate so I get all the bells and whistles. :)

Answer (score 4):

1. In Solution Tree, under the Solution Items Folder, **create a new Test
   Settings file**. (TestSettings1.testsettings)
2. In the Test Setting dialog screen, Select **Data and Diagnostics** on
   the left. Then check enabled for **Code Coverage**
3. On the same screen, **double-click Code Coverage**, then check the .dlls you want to test. Click Apply.
4. In the Visual Studio menu, select **Test, Run, All Tests in Solution**.
5. Once the test run, in the Visual Studio menu, select **Test, Windows...,
   Code Coverage Results**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a product that supports Code Coverage Analysis (Visual Studio Premium or Ultimate, see more details on their features [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare)) you can follow the steps listed here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182534(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: tnx, is there a way to integrate the reports with teamcity ?  i know there's opencover alternative, but since VS ultimate has a tool build in, can we make it work with teamcity?